# Является ли неориентированный взвешенный граф связным

Tags: c#, алгоритм, графы

Подскажите, как наиболее оптимально определить является ли неориентированный взвешенный граф связным?

Comment: А причём здесь взвешенность? И какое у вас представление графа?

Comment: Любой код можно представить абстрактным синтаксическим деревом, которое ВНЕЗАПНО тоже граф. Думаю что закрывать треды про графы на сайте посвященном программированию не очень умно, проголосовал за переоткрытие.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Очевидно, поиск в ширину или глубину от произвольной вершины. Вот вам на C#:

```
var connectedComponent = new HashSet<Vertex>();
var start = vertices.First();
var queue = new Queue<Vertex>();

queue.Enqueue(start);

while (!queue.Empty)
{
    var current = queue.Dequeue();
    connectedComponent.Add(current);
    foreach (var next in current.Neighbours)
    {
        if (!connectedComponent.Contains(next))
            queue.Enqueue(next);
    }
}
```

В конце у вас будет связная компонента, содержащая первую вершину. Просто проверьте, совпадает ли она со всем графом.

```
var isConnected = connectedComponent.Count == vertices.Count;
```