# Определить пару свойств неориентированного взвешенного графа

Tags: c++, c#, алгоритм, графы, дерево

Подскажите, как наиболее оптимально определить данные параметры для неориентированного взвешенного графа( задается матрицей или списком смежности ):

- определить, существуют ли в графе циклы (из одной (любой) вершины вернуться в нее же, проходя по дугам не более одного раза)
- определить, существуют ли в графе Эйлеровы циклы (возможность вернуться в вершину, пройдя по всем вершинам и по всем дугам только 1 раз)
- определить, существуют ли в графе Эйлеровы пути (возможность пройти по всем вершинам графа произвольное количество раз при обязательном условии прохождения по всем дугам точно 1 раз)

Comment: Вы пытались поискать? Эта информация есть в любой методичке по теории графов.
PS. У "оптимальности" нет превосходной степени.

Comment: да, пытался. у Вас случайно нету ссылки на подобную методичку?

Comment: [Вот](http://sfedu.ru/www/umr_main.umr_download?p_umr_id=44988), например.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если граф неориентированный, то определить наличие циклов можно простым обходом (например, [обходом в глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)). Если при обходе вы встречаете вершину, в которой уже были, значит, вы нашли цикл.

Фактически, вам нужно доказать, что граф является деревом. Если вам известно, что граф связный, то достаточно просто посчитать число рёбер: число рёбер в дереве всегда на один меньше, чем число вершин.

Определить, существует ли эйлеров цикл в неориентированном графе довольно просто -- достаточно с помощью любого обхода графа проверить, что он связный и проверить, что нет вершин с нечётной степенью.

Для определения наличия эйлерова пути достаточно проверить связность графа, как в случае с циклом, и удостовериться, что вершин с нечётными степенями нет (тогда путь совпадает с циклом), или есть ровно две.

Про определение связности графа уже есть ответ в вопросе [Является ли неориентированный взвешенный граф связным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426158/%D0%AF%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC).

Comment: Если граф связный, то «число рёбер в дереве всегда на один меньше, чем число вершин» является необходимым и достаточным условием того, что граф — дерево.